# Using Android and Timber or Logback how can I capture native android log messages from third party libraries?

Tags: android, kotlin, logging

When using a third party logging system is there any way to capture log messages made by third party libraries that call

```
android.util.Log.d(TAG, "oops!")
```

The reason I want to do this is I would like to do something else with log messages but I cant capture log message made by libraries that my app is using.